# Wordpress custom post type - error 404

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404, custom-post-type

I read many topic here about this topic, but anything work for me..

So, I have this code in functions PHP:

add_action('init', 'photoplus_init_posttypes');

```
function photoplus_init_posttypes(){
    /* Rejestrujemy zdjęcia */      
    $photos_args = array (
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => 'Zdjęcia',
            'singular_name' => 'Zdjęcia',
            'all_items' => 'Wszystkie zdjęcia',
            'add_new' => 'Dodaj nowe zdjęcie',
            'add_new_item' => 'Dodaj nowe zdjęcie',
            'edit_item' => 'Edytuj zdjęcie',
            'new_item' => 'Nowe zdjęcie',
            'view_items' => 'Zobacz zdjęcie',
            'search_items' => 'Szukaj w zdjęciach',
            'not_found' => 'Nie znaleziono zdjęć',
            'not_found_in_trash' => 'Brak zdjęć w koszu',
            'parent_item_colon' => ''
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'public_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'supports' => array(
            'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments', 'custom-fields'
        ),
        'has_archive' => true
    );

    register_post_type('photos', $photos_args);
}
```

And I get menu, I can add items, bla bla bla.. But When I try "view post" I got error 404. I don't know why, but if I change

```
register_post_type('photos', $photos_args);
```

to

```
register_post_type('recipes', $photos_args);
```

I don't have any error. Where is problem?

Comment: If you change the post type name (from `recipes` to `photos` for ex.) you need to re-save your permalink structure in Settings->Permalinks afterwards.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about this :P. 3h wasted on searching solution ;c